# .Net Core 2.0 project template $safeprojectname$

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-templates

I'm building a .Net Core 2.0 Web API multi-project template which contains 6 different projects, so I've used these links to create my template:

- [How to create your own templates for dotnet new](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/04/02/how-to-create-your-own-templates-for-dotnet-new/#comment-419665)
- [Sidewaffle Creator 2017](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Sayed-Ibrahim-Hashimi.SidewaffleCreator2017)
- [How to create project templates for Visual Studio 2017 (SideWaffle Creator 2017)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g6az_N95dVM)

The problem is that when I create a new project from this template it doesn't replace the template name with the new project name and it makes me manually change the namespace in each and every file and for each and every project.

Here is my template.json:

```
{
  "author": "Liran Friedman",
  "classifications": [],
  "description": ".Net Core Web API project template",
  "name": "project template",
  "defaultName": "Template.Tools.Project",
  "identity": "Template.Tools.CSharp",
  "groupIdentity": "Template.Tools",
  "tags": {
    "language": "C#",
    "type": "project"
  },
  "shortName": "tmpproj",
  "sourceName": "Template.Tools.WebAPI",
  "guids": [],
  "primaryOutputs": [
    {
      "path": "Template.Tools.Common\\Template.Tools.Common.csproj"
    },
    {
      "path": "Template.Tools.External\\Template.Tools.External.csproj"
    },
    {
      "path": "Template.Tools.Implementation\\Template.Tools.Implementation.csproj"
    },
    {
      "path": "Template.Tools.Interfaces\\Template.Tools.Interfaces.csproj"
    },
    {
      "path": "Template.Tools.Models\\Template.Tools.Models.csproj"
    },
    {
      "path": "Template.Tools.WebAPI\\Template.Tools.WebAPI.csproj"
    }
  ]
}
```

and here is my template.vstemplate:

```
<VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005" Type="ProjectGroup">
  <TemplateData>
    <Name>project template</Name>
    <Description>.Net Core Web API project template</Description>
    <TemplateID>Template.Tools.CSharp</TemplateID>
    <DefaultName>Template.Tools.Project</DefaultName>
    <Icon>project-icon.png</Icon>
    <ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
    <NumberOfParentCategoriesToRollUp>1</NumberOfParentCategoriesToRollUp>
    <SortOrder>5000</SortOrder>
    <CreateNewFolder>true</CreateNewFolder>
    <ProvideDefaultName>true</ProvideDefaultName>
    <LocationField>Enabled</LocationField>
    <EnableLocationBrowseButton>true</EnableLocationBrowseButton>
  </TemplateData>
  <TemplateContent>
    <ProjectCollection/>
    <CustomParameters>
      <CustomParameter Name = "$language$" Value="CSharp" />
      <CustomParameter Name = "$uistyle$" Value="none"/>
      <CustomParameter Name = "$groupid$" Value="Template.Tools" />
      <CustomParameter Name = "SideWaffleNewProjNode" Value="CSharp\Template Projects"/>
    </CustomParameters>
  </TemplateContent>
  <WizardExtension>
    <Assembly>Microsoft.VisualStudio.TemplateEngine.Wizard, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a</Assembly>
    <FullClassName>Microsoft.VisualStudio.TemplateEngine.Wizard.TemplateEngineWizard</FullClassName>
  </WizardExtension>
</VSTemplate>
```

I know that in previous versions of creating Visual Studio templates there was a parameter $safeprojectname$ is there any solution for this in the .Net Core template as well?

Answer (score 0):

Basically if you just want to use the old $safeprojectname$ you can edit your  "sourceName": "Template.Tools.WebAPI" attibute in the template.json to match what you want to replace. Let's say you only want to replace "Template" and not "Template.Tools.WebAPI", just change the value of SourceName to "Template". Additionally you can add a "symbols" field to add custom replacement parameters, similar to this:

```
 "symbols": {
  "foo-rename": {
    "type": "parameter",
    "datatype": "string",
    "replaces": "foo",
    "defaultValue": "new-component",
    "description": "Renames component"
  },
}
```

This will replace every occurrence of "foo" in every file your template contains. However, this is not applicable to file or folder names when using Sidewaffle Creator. But don't pin me on that one because I haven't completely figured it out. I would just wait for answers on these two github issues: 
https://github.com/dotnet/templating/issues/396
https://github.com/ligershark/sidewafflev2/issues/32